# How to export radgridview contents to excel?

Tags: c#, excel, telerik, radgridview

i am trying to export the radgridview (telerik grid view) content to excel in c#. following is my code (on button click event):

> `ExportToExcelML exp = new ExportToExcelML(radGridView1);`
>   `exp.ExportVisualSettings = true;`
>   `exp.SheetName = "Report";`
>   `string fileName = "F:\\Temp.xls";`
>   `exp.RunExport(fileName);`

but i am getting this exception

> The DateTime Value is not Supported in Excel. 
>   can anyone help me?

Comment: and yes.. i have a datetime field in my gridview..